# Execute many different INSERT statements efficiently

Tags: python, mysql

I am working with a system that puts failed MySQL statements into a log file along with other errors. **Edit**: The statements fail due to a lost connection generally. I wrote a simple python script that scans through a log file looking for INSERT statements, formats them, and creates a List of strings

It is unlikely that any of the strings are invalid MySQL statements, but they also have no common structure (they INSERT INTO different tables, different columns, etc.). Assuming that they are all valid MySQL statements, is there a better method to execute them than this?

```
count = 0
for i, statement in enumerate(insertStatements):
        if i%10000 == 0:
                print "Completed " + str(i) + " of " + str(num) + ", " + str(float(i)/num*100.0) + "%"

        # An earlier step split by "INSERT INTO"
        # The MySQL statement is terminated by a '"'
        insertStatements[i] = "INSERT INTO" + statement.split('"')[0]

        try:
                cursor.execute(insertStatements[i])
                count += 1
        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
                print e
                print insertStatements[i] + '\n'

cnx.commit()
```

It is likely that any given log will produce many MySQL statements, the one I was testing with had 4,794,454 INSERT statements

Comment: Why do the statements fail?

Comment: @SimeonVisser, forgot to add that, generally they fail due to a lost connection

Comment: I would improve the root problem first to reduce the number of failed statements - but yes, otherwise you'd have to rerun the queries to insert the data.

Comment: Could you provide several example statements?

Comment: @alecxe, I can't, it is for work and the information is sensitive. The general structure is usually `INSERT INTO someTable (...) VALUES (...)` or `INSERT INTO someTable (...) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` but I can't really count on either structure. Also "someTable" can mean different tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take your question to mean, "Is there a more efficient way to narrow down which of my millions of INSERT queries will fail than testing each one individually?"  I can think of a couple of approaches.  One would be to open multiple connections to the db and run them in parallel.  The second (if the # of queries that actually do fail is fairly small) would be to batch them and narrow down the misfits.

[Batch inserting rows can be orders of magnitude faster](http://blog.cnizz.com/2010/05/31/optimize-mysql-queries-fast-mutliple-row-inserts/) than sending each one individually across the wire, since you save on the overhead of network round trips, possible I/O round trips, and query planning.  [(Keep in mind you might have to increase the max packet size)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html) But with your naive error checking this would not pinpoint which query failed, which is what you want.  However you could implement a sort of binary search trial and error algorithm that could narrow down the culprits:

1. Send 100K INSERTS
2. If success, send next 100K
3. Else roll back and repeat with first 50K, then with second 50K

The idea being that if step #2 is likely to succeed, you've saved yourself a ton of time.  You should adjust the batch # to be some n that is empirically likely to succeed.

Comment: In the log file I tried out today none actually threw any errors, it didn't occur to me that I could send many and then check if any threw errors, that is a good idea (it is possible although unlikely that some will throw errors). However, I can't count on any particular structure for the INSERTs, can this batch be done without knowing that?

Comment: So are you just trying to replay failed inserts?  Batch inserts are done per table, so you would need to group them.  If that gets too complex you may just want to go with my first approach and open up a bunch of parallel connections.